# postgresql, php, ERROR: syntax error at or near

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to store the data from a form into a postgresql but I am getting the error

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
>   LINE 2: ..., '1212121212', '01/06/2000', 'Gurjeet', 'Singh',
>   ,'12121212... ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 36 Error with
>   query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 2: ..., '1212121212',
>   '01/06/2000', 'Gurjeet', 'Singh', ,'12121212... ^

The values in the single inverted commas are the value that I have given input through the html form.
Here is my php code

```
    if(isset( $_POST['econtct']))
$emergency_number = $_POST['econtct']; 

$mobile             = 1212121212;
if(isset( $_POST['date']))
$   DOB                 = $_POST['date'];
if(isset( $_POST['fnam']))
$first_name         = $_POST['fnam'];
if(isset( $_POST['lnam']))
$last_name      = $_POST['lnam'];


  //$blood_group        = $_POST['bgr'];

if(isset( $_POST['uidd']))
$aadhar             = $_POST['uidd'];
if(isset( $_POST['address']))
$address            = $_POST['address'];

$query = "INSERT INTO user_details (emergency_number, mobile, DOB, first_name, last_name, aadhar, address)
    VALUES ('$emergency_number', '$mobile', '$DOB', '$first_name', '$last_name', ,'$aadhar', '$address' )";

$result = pg_query($db,$query);
if (!$result) {
    $errormessage = pg_last_error();
    echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
    exit();
}
printf ("These values were inserted into the database");
pg_close();
```

Comment: Please get your code proper aligned in your IDE before posting. This is very difficult to read.

Comment: You're probably getting SQL errors because there's a character with significance to SQL in your input and you're doing NOTHING TO FILTER YOUR INPUT!  This code is wide open to all kinds of SQL injection abuse.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

`VALUES ('$emergency_number', '$mobile', '$DOB', '$first_name', '$last_name', ,'$aadhar', '$address' )";`

You have two commas between $last_name and $aadhar

Answer (score 1):

There seems to an extra comma in your query:

**Incorrect:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_details (emergency_number, mobile, DOB, first_name, last_name, aadhar, address)
        VALUES ('$emergency_number', '$mobile', '$DOB', '$first_name', '$last_name', ,'$aadhar', '$address' )";
```

**Correct:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_details (emergency_number, mobile, DOB, first_name, last_name, aadhar, address)
        VALUES ('$emergency_number', '$mobile', '$DOB', '$first_name', '$last_name','$aadhar', '$address' )";
```

Can you remove that and try once again